# Behaviour of REST service using HTTPServletRequest and using @PathVariable

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

Below are the two scenarios that I came across while coding services for a project in school.

## Scenario 1

```
@RequestMapping("/customer/firstName/")
public CustomerRepresentation getCustomersByFirstName(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String name = request.getParameter("fname");
    List<Customer> customer = customerActivity.findByCustFirstName(name);
    // etc
}
```

## Scenario 2

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/firstName/{fname}",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"text/html","application/json", "application/xml"})
public @ResponseBody List<CustomerRepresentation> getCustomersByFirstName(@PathVariable("fname") String name) {
    List<Customer> customer = customerActivity.findByCustFirstName(name);
    // etc
}
```

Behaviour:

1. If I use the first approach, I am able to access the results using the link from any browser and even from Postman.
2. If I use the second approach, I am able to access the results using Postman only when I specify Accept Headers. If I use the browser it gives me error 406, type not supported.
3. Using the client both are working fine with minor modifications to the URL.

What causes this? I assume the default settings in `HttpServletRequest`? If we use the second approach, how will the websites function, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: view the network data in the browser dev tools and see what the service states is accept header is on the second endpint. My guess is that when you add produces the framework automatically adds consumes header to perhaps json due to the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two URIs are different on principle, and shouldn't be considered the same at all.

First, there's a huge difference between a path variable and a query parameter - path variables are *required* to be part of the path, or the path won't be accessible.  It's the difference in these two URIs:

```
/customer/firstName?fname=Bob
/customer/firstName/Bob
```

You can't access the second URI without Bob, as opposed to the first URI; you may be asking for something *other* than `fname`.

Second, the reason you have to have your `Accept` headers set is due to the way your `produces` array is set up:  you have `text/html`, `application/json`, and `application/xml`; your client won't be able to accept anything that's not one of those three types.

Third, to directly answer the last question, I would explicitly discourage your second approach because of the way path variables should be partitioned.  The path describes some information that is *required* for the request to continue; here, you're only asking information about the customer, which should be contained to a query.

In that vein, your request URI should *really* just be `customer` with a query for `firstName`.

```
/customer?firstName=Bob
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But my browser passes the content-type as null by default and thus the code breaks if I use the second approach. it is handled automatically by the first one. So yes I will go with the first one as you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you specify

```
produces = {"text/html","application/json", "application/xml"}
```

you need to send Accept header with one of that types. 
Some clients use default Accept header and it can be different from what you expect.